# sane-find-scanner does not detect Brother DS-720D but simple scan and xsane does

Tags: 16.04, scanner, sane

I have Brother DS-720D and connected it on a newly installed ubuntu 16.04. I installed the drivers `libsane-dsseries`from Brother's website. The scanner works and xsane and simple scan detects it. However using `sudo sane-find-scanner` does not detect it and simply outputs the `#No USB scanners found`. I verified that the `libsane-dsseries.so` files are in the `/usr/lib/x86_64/sane` folder. I tried other solutions like:

1. Reinstalling the drivers
2. Verifying that from `lsusb` it is detected
3. Editing the `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules` and adding the lines:

   ```
   #Brother 
   ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
   ```